# How do I get the value of a variable to decrease by 1 every time the user enters something incorrect?

Tags: python

This is a python program exercise called guess the word from codehs.com. It basically works like hangman. The user has 10 lives and I'm trying to decrease the lives by one when the user guesses an incorrect letter. However, it always says there are 9 incorrect guesses remaining no matter how many times a user guesses an incorrect letter. How do I fix the program so that it decreases by one all the way down to 0 incorrect guesses left? Furthermore, how do I say that the user lost and terminate the program when he/she has zero incorrect guesses left? Thanks so much.

```
#initializes the secret word and starts with empty dashes list
secret_word = "eggplant"
dashes_list = []

def get_guess():
    #prompts user for a guess
    guess = input("Guess: ")
    dashes = "-"
    guesses_left=10
    #if the guess is not one character
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print ("Your guess must have exactly one character!")
    #if the guess is not lowercase
    elif not guess.islower():
        print ("Your guess must be a lowercase letter!")
    #assigns this position_of_letter variable to be used later
    position_of_letter = 0
    for letter in secret_word:
            if guess == letter:
                print ("Letter is in secret word.")
                update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess)
                return
            else:
                position_of_letter += 1
                if position_of_letter == len(secret_word):
                    print ("Letter is not in the secret word.")
                    if guesses_left==0:
                        print("You lose. The word was "+secret_word)
                    guesses_left-=1
                    print (str(guesses_left)+" incorrect guesses left.")
#This goes through the word and makes sure to update
#the dashes at the right place
def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    position_of_letter_dashes_list = 0
    for letter in secret_word:
        if letter == guess:
            dashes_list[position_of_letter_dashes_list] = guess
        position_of_letter_dashes_list += 1

#adds a dash mark for each letter so there is now a list of dashes
for i in range(len(secret_word)):
    dashes_list.append("-")
#The .join breaks the dashes list into a continuous string of dashes
#The "" is there so that nothing comes before each dash
while True:
    print ("".join(dashes_list))
    get_guess()
    if "-" not in dashes_list:
        print("Congrats! You win. The word was "+secret_word+".")
        break
```

Comment: You're setting `guesses_left` to 10 every time you call `get_guess()`, so it can't keep decreasing each time. You need to store the value in the `while True:` loop, and pass it into `get_guess()` as an argument.

Comment: What have you done to try and figure it out and where are you stuck?  **Safety tip:** Don't just download open-source code and run it **until you know what it does**.

Comment: What does that look like?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent!  Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing number of `guesses_left=10` each time so the value of `guesses_left` is not decreasing with every incorrect guess. You can initialize its value outside the `get_guess()` as a global variable or pass it as a parameter to this function.